# Why does SELinux blocks mounting on HTTPD's www folder?

Tags: linux, permissions, mount, selinux

It took me a while and I had to use ChatGPT to understand, that when I do the following command:

```
# mount /dev/MyVG/MyLVWithFileSystem /var/www/html
```

I won't get my lv that stores my website files because **SELinux is blocking it**, and I know that I can disable SELinux and then i'll get my website files, but I must understand - Why does SELinux blocks my LV from being mounted on my html directory?

(I mean, when I'll do `ls -l` on that folder, I will see my website files. However when i'll use my web browser to access my website, it will return a Forbidden or even worse, Not Found)

Also, SELinux blocks my Samba directory from writing on Windows - I can log in to the "share", but I can't make any folder or file because I don't have permissions, even though I used the `chown nobody:nobody` command on that very folder.

Why is SELinux a pain in my [bullock](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTI5NDY5NjU3NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMzQ0MTMyMw@@._V1_FMjpg_UX1000_.jpg)s and how to learn to live with it in peace? I really want to terminate it, but I understand that I must learn it, though it's very tough for me. I am a Rocky Linux Newbie so any help will be more than appreciated :)

Comment: Can you edit your question with the result of `audit2allow -a` and `ls -lahZ /var/www/html`